# absolute values and integals

Tags: integration, notation, absolute-value

I have the following integral

$$\int_{- \infty}^\infty e^{-|x|} dx$$

and the following two questions

(1)
Since the preimages $x$ determine the the images $e^{-|x|}$ for nonnegative and negative preimages, I was wondering if splitting the integral into two integrals with the following limits of integration is correct

$$\lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0^-} \enspace \int_{- \infty}^{c} e^{-|x|} \enspace dx \quad + \quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- |x|} \enspace dx$$

where $c$ obviously approaches $0$ from below without necessarily equalling $0$, so that $e^{- |x|} = e{-(-x)}$. So,

$$\lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0^-} \enspace \int_{- \infty}^{c} e^{-|x|} \enspace dx \quad + \quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- |x|} \enspace dx $$

$$= \lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0^-} \enspace \int_{- \infty}^{c} e^{x} \enspace dx \quad + \quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \enspace dx $$

$$= 2$$

So I was wondering if the above integrals is correct, especially with the use of the limit; and then,

(2) Is the following integral incorrect, because I think it is

$$\int_{- \infty}^{0} e^{-|x|} \enspace dx \quad + \quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- |x|} \enspace dx$$

where my issue is with the upper limit of integration $0$ of the first integral, since the $x$ spans negative values and $0$, causing problems with the integrand due to the absolute value.

Also,I know that the function $f$ is even, so it is better to use the following identity in order for my problem to be easily avoided

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \enspace dx = 2 \int_0^{\infty} f(x) \enspace$$

but I'm very curious to see an answer to my questions above.

Comment: For $x\geq 0$ we have $e^{-x}$, and for $x<0$ we have $e^{x}$, so I think it's $\int_{-\infty }^{0}{e^{x}dx}+\int_{0}^{\infty }{e^{-x}dx}$